# Simple pin joint in SpriteKit doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I'd like to make a pendulum.  Starting with an SKScene and everything defaulted, I do the following...

```
- (void)createSceneContents {
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.view.bounds];

    // object 1 is the fulcrum
    SKSpriteNode *object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
    [self addChild:object1];
    object1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object1.frame.size];
    object1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    object1.position = self.view.center;

    // object2 is like a broomstick, which I will pin to the fulcrum
    SKSpriteNode *object2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(90, 2)];
    [self addChild:object2];
    object2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    object2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object2.frame.size];
    object2.position = self.view.center;

    // pin the physics bodies
    SKPhysicsJointPin *pinJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:object1.physicsBody bodyB:object2.physicsBody anchor:object1.position];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:pinJoint];
}
```

If I don't add the pin logic, as expected the fulcrum stays in the middle of the scene and the broomstick falls to the floor, so I know the broomstick is subject to gravity.  After adding the pin, I get this:

[image]

No motion. Why? This causes no motion either...

```
[object2.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0, -5)];
```

I expect the broomstick to swing and oscillate because it's pinned to the fulcrum.  I've seen articles about positioning the nodes first, before joints, but I've done that.  Am I wrong to expect the broom to swing?  How can I get it to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node 2 have bad defined anchorPoint, here an upload an example:

[Full code of example](https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/tree/master/TestJoint)

Image:

[image: 3 Seconds running code]

Swift 3 code:

```
    let nodeSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: nodeSize)
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: nodeSize)
    node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.addChild(node)

    let node2Size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 8)
    let node2 = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: node2Size)
    node2.position = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 0)
    node2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node2Size)
    node2.physicsBody?.mass = 1.0
    self.addChild(node2)


    let a = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: node.physicsBody! , bodyB: node2.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    self.physicsWorld.add(a)
```

Objective-C:

```
SKSpriteNode *object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
[self addChild:object1];
object1.position = self.view.center;
object1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object1.frame.size];
object1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKSpriteNode *object2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(90, 2)];
[self addChild:object2];
object2.position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x+45, self.view.center.y);

object2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object2.frame.size];

SKPhysicsJointPin *pinJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:object1.physicsBody bodyB:object2.physicsBody anchor:self.view.center];
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:pinJoint];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I posted objective C translation.  (Not sure how you got this to work without positioning the node).

Comment: For default, the node is set on 0,0, node2 is set on another position :)

Comment: Thanks again for this.  It has led me to a new problem, which I ask about here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259118/scaling-a-pendulum-made-with-skspritenodes  Would sure appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Maetschl, I was able to make it work in Objective-c as follows (removing the anchor point and just positioning the swinging node to one edge)...

```
SKSpriteNode *object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
[self addChild:object1];
object1.position = self.view.center;
object1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object1.frame.size];
object1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKSpriteNode *object2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(90, 2)];
[self addChild:object2];
object2.position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x+45, self.view.center.y);

object2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object2.frame.size];

SKPhysicsJointPin *pinJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:object1.physicsBody bodyB:object2.physicsBody anchor:self.view.center];
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:pinJoint];
```